# jquery validate change error messages on invalidHandler

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I saw the documentation on jquery validate plugin for invalidHandler [on the website](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler).  I was hoping to be able to do something like the following?

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
    if (errors) {
     for (var i = 0, len = errors.length; i < len; i++) {
         errors[i].text = //replace special characters in message (if any) and replace with something else)
      } 
    }

    //update list of changed error messages back to validator, so new error messages show
  }
});
```

I'm trying to do it this way because I'm trying to do it globally.  Basically I'm trying to convert a simpler markup into a hyperlink, and was hoping to be able to do this globally.

Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  Why not simply try it?

Comment: FWIW, if you're using the unobtrusive-validation plugin, then you cannot use the `.validate()` method since unobtrusive constructs that automatically.  You're then confined to setting options using [the `.setDefaults()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/).

Comment: @Sparky I know how to do string replacements in jquery, but I don't know how I can then update the original list.  Usually, these components give you a "read" copy, not an "editable" copy of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply validate settings to a selector like this:

```
var valSettings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
valSettings.invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // do something
}
```

Of if you want it truly global for the entire plugin, use [`jQuery.validator.setDefaults()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/):

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: My question is more about how I can modify and update the messages that appear in the UI.